# Interaction between components in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I need to understand how to lift up the state and methods of classes to the parent component if there are several components and the only common parent component. In my example of code there are some buttons displayed as a list of "li" 
elements. The click on any button should change the text in the text block, but it doesn't change it. Plz help me find my error. Here my code:

```
class TextBlock extends React.Component {
    render() {      
         return <div id="textDiv">{this.props.text}</div>;
     }
 }

class MyButton extends React.Component { 
    render() {          
        return <button id={this.props.id} className="mybutton"> 
       {this.props.label}</button>;  
    }
}

class ButtonsList extends React.Component { 
    clickButton=(e)=> {
    this.props.handlerButtons(e);
}

    render() {      
        return(
            <ul>
              {buttons.map((button)=> <MyButton id={button.id} label= 
              {button.label} onClick={this.clickButton}/>)}         
          </ul>
         ); 
    }
}

class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);      
        this.state={text: "My text"};   
}

    handlerButtons=(e)=> {
    this.setState({text: "The changed text"});
    }   

    render() {      

        return( <div>
                 <TextBlock text={this.state.text}/>
                 <ButtonsList handlerButtons={this.handlerButtons}/>                    
            </div>
          );
    }
}
const buttons=[{id: "id1", label: "1"}, {id: "id2", label: "2"},
{id: "id3", label: "3"}, {id: "id4", label: "4"}, {id: "id5", label: "5"}];

 ReactDOM.render(
    <ParentComponent/>,     
     document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add onClick to your button in MyButton component which is missing

```
class MyButton extends React.Component { 
    render() {          
        return <button id={this.props.id} className="mybutton" onClick={this.props.onClick}> 
       {this.props.label}</button>;  
    }
}
```

Comment: NP. Kindly do upvote and accept my answer if it resolved your issue

Comment: How to upvote? Explain me what should I do and how, bse I'm new on this site and I don't know the rules.